# Flutter pusher_client fail to connect to BeyondCode/laravel-websockets

Tags: laravel, flutter, pusher

I'm using [pusher_client](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_client) ^2.0.0 to connect to self-hosted [laravel-websockets server](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets), but the connection keeps failing.

The code I am using to connect to the server is:

```
PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
      host: '100.127.255.249',
      port: 6001,
      encrypted: true,
    );

    PusherClient pusherClient = PusherClient(
      'appKey',
      options,
      autoConnect: false,
      enableLogging: true,
    );

    pusherClient.connect();
```

Note: The host is my localhost IP.

how to solve this issue?